# Unable to get Postgresql database to work with Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

**Environment**

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Ruby 1.8.7
- Rails 3.0.0
- pg AdminIII
- PostgreSQL 9.0.3
- Cygwin

**Gemfile**

http://i54.tinypic.com/27yzxv4.png

**Database Config**

http://i53.tinypic.com/288b7ma.png

**Steps I have taken**

- I tried addding "gem 'postgres-pr', :require => 'pg'" to the gemfile
- Have tried installing multiple variations of the postgres gem,

  - postgres-pr
  - pg
  - ruby-pg

I continually get this error when trying to run rake db:migrate

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- pg
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
/home/Other/rails_projects/test_project/config/application.rb:7
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
/home/Other/rails_projects/test_project/Rakefile:4
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Been at this for a couple days, really need some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the correct platform for the gem. In my Gemfile, I have:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg', :platforms => :mingw
end
```

(The group is there because I deploy to a Unix box, where the platform is obviously different). I seem to remember that I also needed the [DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit) for this to work.

Comment: I got the pg gem installed with plaform mingw and then I put devkit into my home folder for cygwin and i'm still getting the 

rake aborted!
no such file to load -- pg

error

Comment: Ah, you don't need the DevKit after gem installation, it is necessary for some gems to build.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pg and add to your Gemfile

```
gem 'pg'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to upgrade your version of Rails to 3.0.1 - 3.0.9 and also run `gem install pg`. Then just for good measure re-run `bundle install`.